# replacing href action with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, zen-cart

I have the following generated href link on a product list page

```
<a title="Add to My Favourites" class="a2f-link" href="http://epicurium.localhost/by-lifestyle-diet/breakfast?sort=20a&amp;products_id=1838&amp;action=add_to_favourites">
    <img src="images/icons/favourites.png" alt="Add to My Favourites" title=" Add to My Favourites " width="16" height="16" class="fl_add" />
</a>
```

The php that generates this href link is

```
public function add_to_favourites_link($products_id, $product_value) 
{
    if (!isset($this->icon)) {
        $this->icon = (FAVOURITES_LISTING_ICON == 'Font Awesome') ? FA_ADD_TO_FAVOURITES : zen_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . 'icons/' . BUTTON_ADD_TO_FAVOURITES, BUTTON_ADD_TO_FAVOURITES_ALT, '', '','class="fl_add"');
    }

    $page_link = zen_href_link($GLOBALS['current_page_base'], zen_get_all_get_params(array('products_id', 'action')) . 'products_id=' . (int)$products_id . '&action=add_to_favourites');

    return ($this->favouritesEnabled) ? sprintf('<span class="a2f-wrap"><a title="%4$s" class="a2f-link" href="%2$s">%3$s</a><span class="a2f-value">%1$s</span></span>', $product_value, $page_link, $this->icon, BUTTON_ADD_TO_FAVOURITES_ALT) : '';
}
```

In another file I have

```
case 'add_to_favourites':
  if (isset($_GET['products_id'])) {
    if (zen_has_product_attributes($_GET['products_id'])) {
      $messageStack->add_session('product_info', sprintf(CAUTION_PRODUCT_HAS_ATTRIBUTES, zen_get_products_name($_GET['products_id'])), 'caution');
          zen_redirect(zen_href_link(zen_get_info_page($_GET['products_id']), zen_get_all_get_params(array('action'))));
    } else {
      if (!(isset($_SESSION['customer_id']) && zen_not_null($_SESSION['customer_id']))) {
        $messageStack->add_session('login', CAUTION_LOGIN_REQUIRED_FOR_FAVOURITES, 'caution');
        $_SESSION['navigation']->set_snapshot();
        zen_redirect(zen_href_link(FILENAME_LOGIN, '', 'SSL')); 
      }
      $favourites = new favourites();
      $favourites->addToFavourites($_GET['products_id'], (FAVOURITES_SHOW_ON_ADD == 'true') ? 'favourites' : 'header');
      if (FAVOURITES_SHOW_ON_ADD == 'true') {
        zen_redirect(zen_href_link(FILENAME_FAVOURITES, '', 'SSL'));
      } else {
        zen_redirect(zen_href_link($current_page_base, zen_get_all_get_params(array('action', 'products_id'))));
      }
    }
  }
break;
```

I want to change this to work via AJAX so I have no page reload, but to be honest, I have no idea where to start modifying an href link into an AJAX call.
The only AJAX I've ever attempted was submitting a simple form via a button, where the file the AJAX linked to was specific to that process, not part of a switch.

I've done a search online, and via SO and not found any examples of how this is done.

Any advice or examples welcome!

Comment: It's not clear how your anchor is being used. You might slim down your PHP snippet to just what's relevant (and tag it properly). If this question relies on Zen functionality it should be tagged as such.

Comment: In fact, I'm starting to doubt that the anchor markup you've shown is even relevant. This seems like a PHP question, or you need to study ajax and make an effort before asking. Is your question about PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: @isherwood I can assure you that the generated html I posted is used to trigger case 'add_to_favourites': as posted.

As stated in my question, I have done a small amount of AJAX in the past, but it was for a form submit, not an href link with an action. I searched google for some information on doing this and came up with nothing.
If I don't want a page reload when the action is complete, then I need to use AJAX, so it isn't a PHP question.

Answer (score 1):

give id to anchor tag and write script for ajax

```
<a id="add_fav" href="javascript:void(0)" ..> img src="">...

$(document).on('click','#add_fav',function(){
   //write your ajax call here
   $.ajax({
      url : 'your_controller_method',
      type : 'GET', or "POST" select accordingly 
      data : {'product_id' : 1838,
             ....
          },
     dataType:'json',
     success : function(data) {              
          alert('Data: '+data);
         },
     error : function(request,error){
     }
   });
 })
or you can make javascript function and pass data to function and then set it to ajax data
```